# Marionette CompositeView -- Control Model Passed to ChildView

Tags: marionette

I have a view that I want to reuse in a `CompositiveView`, that reusable view need to be fed a model with an specific set of properties and each member of the collection passed to the `CompositiveView` has does properties but encapsulated in an inner object, like this:

```
{
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
    objWithStuffThatINeed: {
        ...
    }
}
```

The reusable view have to idea of this hierarchy and I can not change that view to make it aware of this. I was wondering if there is a way to pass **only** that `objWithStuffThatINeed` to the `childView` instead of the whole item in the current iteration of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change model of ItemView which use only fields you need.

```js
$(function() {
    // You reusable view.       
    var ExampleItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        template:  _.template('<%- baz%>'),
    });
    
    var ExampleCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    
        tagName: "ul",
        childView: ExampleItemView,
        template: _.template(''),
        
        buildChildView: function(child, ChildViewClass, childViewOptions) {
          // create the child view instance
          var view = new ChildViewClass( {
            model: new Backbone.Model(child.get('objWithStuffThatINeed'))
          });
          // return it
          return view;
        }
        
    });
    
    var testCollection = new Backbone.Collection(
      [{
          foo: 'foo1',
          bar: 'bar1',
          objWithStuffThatINeed: {
            baz: "baz1"
          }
      },
      {
          foo: 'foo2',
          bar: 'bar2',
          objWithStuffThatINeed: {
            baz: "baz2"
          }
      }
      ]
    );
    
    var region = new  Backbone.Marionette.Region({
      el: '.main-region'
    });
    
    region.show(new ExampleCompositeView({
      collection: testCollection
    }));
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="underscore.js@*" data-semver="1.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="backbone.js@*" data-semver="1.1.2" src="    //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="marionette.js@*" data-semver="2.2.2" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.2.2/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main-region"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly, I wonder why this function is not in the documentation? Thank you very much @sergey-ratnikov

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`childViewOptions`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childviewoptions) (which complements [`childView`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childview)) to not only provide additional constructor options for child views, but also to *override constructor options provided by [`CollectionView`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.collectionview.html) itself*, namely the `model`.

```
var MyCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

  childView: MyChildView,

  childViewOptions: function (child) {
    // Override the model otherwise provided by CollectionView
    return {
      model: new Backbone.Model(child.get('objWithStuffThatINeed'))
    };
  },

  ...

});
```

The original [`buildChildView`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-buildchildview) looks like this:

```
buildChildView: function(child, ChildViewClass, childViewOptions) {
  var options = _.extend({model: child}, childViewOptions);
  return new ChildViewClass(options);
}
```

You can override it too, if you need to do something more to create a child view, than calling an object constructor with options.